# List top 10 item pairs with most values in common MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table of miRNAs and DNA (genes).  Each miRNA regulates many different genes.  The goal is to list the top 10 miRNAS with the most genes regulated in common.

The table I'm working with has 89,043 rows and looks like this:

```
mid   gid
-----------
1     1       
1     297     
1     305     
1     394     
1     450     
2     1       
2     2       
2     61      
2     72      
3     1       
3     12      
3     61      
3     450
```

mid stands for miRNA; gid is Gene.  Each miRNA regulates multiple genes as you can see.  There are 1498 miRNAs regulating ~30-40 Genes each.  The goal would be to create a set of Genes regulated by each miRNA and then somehow see which values each set shares with the other sets, count the shared values, order the shared data by count, and select the top 10.  I have no idea how to do sets and comparison stuff in MySQL...not even sure if you can; seems more like a job for Python...

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:  I need to find the top 10 *pairs* of miRNA that have the greatest number of genes regulated in common.  For instance, miRNA #17 and #42 each regulate 30 of the *same* genes, not just 30 genes in general.  I don't really know how to do such comparisons...

Answer (score 2):

Finding the top ten miRNA items is a simple aggregate query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) genes_regulated,
       mid
  FROM the_table
 GROUP BY mid
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

**Edit** But you're looking for the pairs of miRNAs that regulate genes in common.

So, let's work it out. the combinatorial capability of `JOIN` can help greatly here.  This query will give lists of pairs of `mid` items that have the same `gid`. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2279bb/3/0)

```
      SELECT a.mid amid, b.mid bmid, a.gid
        FROM t a
        JOIN t b ON a.gid = b.gid AND a.mid < b.mid
```

This query gives one row per pair of mids that refer to the same gid. Notice that the `ON` clause both matches gids between the table, and also prevents self matches (where a.mid = b.mid) and duplicate pairs, that is (q,r) and (r,q).

Next, we need to summarize that virtual table -- subquery -- of pairs. That's a simple `COUNT() ... GROUP BY` aggregate query. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2279bb/4/0)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) mid_pair_count, gid
  FROM (
          SELECT a.mid amid, b.mid bmid, a.gid
            FROM t a
            JOIN t b ON a.gid = b.gid AND a.mid < b.mid
        ) pairs
 GROUP BY gid
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

**Edit**  if you want the identities of the miRNA pairs in order by number of genes, instead of genes in order by pairs of miRNAs regulating them, it's a trivial change to the query. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2279bb/5/0)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) gene_count, amid, bmid
  FROM (
          SELECT a.mid amid, b.mid bmid, a.gid
            FROM t a
            JOIN t b ON a.gid = b.gid AND a.mid < b.mid
        ) pairs
 GROUP BY amid, bmid
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

Finally (and here's where the *structured* in *structured query language* starts to really kick in, you can get a list of which genes are regulated by each pair in your top ten, using `GROUP_CONCAT()`.   (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2279bb/7/0)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) gene_count, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(gid ORDER BY gid) gene_list,
       amid, bmid
  FROM (
          SELECT a.mid amid, b.mid bmid, a.gid
            FROM t a
            JOIN t b ON a.gid = b.gid AND a.mid < b.mid
        ) pairs
 GROUP BY amid, bmid
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

The point is this: SQL is at its heart a set-processing tool. You can use SQL `JOIN` to perform a combinatorial explosion. You can restrict that combinatorial explosion by judicious use on `JOIN  ... ON`. And finally, you can summarize the combinations by `GROUP BY`. Joining a table to itself is a powerful way to explore coincidences and combinations.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!  I just realized that I need to find the top 10 *pairs* of miRNA that have the greatest number of genes regulated in common.  For instance, miRNA #17 and #42 each regulate 30 of the *same* genes, not just 30 genes in general.  I don't really know how to do such comparisons...

Comment: Gotcha!  Thank you for your help, Ollie.  That makes a lot of sense, and I follow what you've done there.  However that second portion of code selects a count rather than the actual 10 pairs of mid's in descending order by the number of genes they regulate in common.  The output should in theory look like:  mid1, mid2, # of genes regulated.  Sorry for all the confusion!

Comment: Ah.  I thought you wanted the genes regulated.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 select mid,count(gid) from TABLE group by mid ORDER BY count(gid)
```